# Python - How to replace spaces in simple line of text with a specific character

Tags: python-2.7, formatting

I am looking for some help in reformatting a line of text, from within a python script, so that I can replace certain characters with others, or spaces with a specific character. For clarity, the text I am trying to reformat is assigned to a  variable.

I have searched for this feature but I have not seen how this can be done!

Comment: Please add sample text to your question

Comment: search here https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace, does pretty much exactly what you described.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for. I was on that page already but I got confused early on and never got to that command!!

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to write a full function for you to fit your purpose:

```
 def posSubStringReplaceRecursively(string1, search, replace, pos, is_First):
    global string2
    if is_First:
        string2 = list(copy.deepcopy(string1))
        is_First = False
    index = str.rfind(string1, search)
    if index != -1:
        string1 = string1[:(index+len(search)-1)]
        pos.append(index)
        return posSubStringReplaceRecursively(string1, search, replace, pos, is_First)
    else:
        pos = pos

    for i in xrange(len(pos)):
        string2[pos[i]:pos[i]+len(search)] = replace
    string2 = " ".join(string2)
    return string2
```

Calling the function:

```
string1 = raw_input("Enter string:\n")
search = raw_input("Enter word to find:\n")
replace = raw_input("Enter word to replace:\n")
print posSubStringReplaceRecursively(string1, search, replace, [], True)
```